# Join/merge not working in python

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to join df61 and df_petsy_gz on pic_code. I've included the data types for the variables also. My code is outputting a bunch of NaN indicating none of the pic_codes match between the two data sets. There are a couple million lines of data so I'm certain there are a bunch of matches. I think I'm doing something wrong.

```
df61.head(3)

 mpe_wgt                        pic_code
      10  420336479305589843900801597032
      10  420907139300189843900792911982
      10  420967449300189843900797682603

mpe_wgt     object
pic_code    object


df_petsy_gz.head(3)

monthly_fiscal_year  month                        pic_code class_of_mail  
               2017     11  420606019300189843900566128707            FC   
               2017     11  420731629300189843900584700299            FC   
               2017     11  420405029300189843900568579224            FC   

   weight  calc_postage  calc_total_postage  MikeZone  
   0.8750          4.02                4.02         5  
   0.3750          2.77                2.77         6  
   0.6875          3.60                3.60         8 

 monthly_fiscal_year      int64
 month                    int64
 pic_code                object
 class_of_mail           object
 weight                 float64
 calc_postage           float64
 calc_total_postage     float64
 MikeZone                 int64

 df61_mpe=pd.merge(df_petsy_gz,df61,on='pic_code', how='outer')
```

output

```
monthly_fiscal_year  month                        pic_code class_of_mail  \
             2017.0   11.0  420606019300189843900566128707            FC   
             2017.0   11.0  420731629300189843900584700299            FC   
             2017.0   11.0  420405029300189843900568579224            FC   
             2017.0   11.0  420301349300189843900567382542            FC   

   weight  calc_postage  calc_total_postage  MikeZone mpe_wgt  
   0.8750          4.02                4.02       5.0     NaN  
   0.3750          2.77                2.77       6.0     NaN  
   0.6875          3.60                3.60       8.0     NaN  
   0.5000          2.77                2.77       4.0     NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your data looks like but all what i know is that the type of join affects how the rows will be formed after the join.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

```
how : {‘left’, ‘right’, ‘outer’, ‘inner’}, default: ‘left’

How to handle the operation of the two objects.

left: use calling frame’s index (or column if on is specified)
right: use other frame’s index
outer: form union of calling frame’s index (or column if on is specified) with other frame’s index, and sort it lexicographically
inner: form intersection of calling frame’s index (or column if on is specified) with other frame’s index, preserving the order of the calling’s one
```

Try using **'inner'** join and see if that is what you need.
This will only return rows of where **pic_code** is found in both dataframes and having **mpe_wgt**.

Additionally make sure that the pic_code has no trailing/leading whitespaces so that similar pic_code from the two dataframes would match.

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation, inner performs an intersection operation between the two dataframe while outer performs a union operation. So, inner join will return a subset of the dataframe that is returned by the outer join.